# How to fill a vector with a range?

Tags: c++, vector

How would I fill a vector with the numbers from 1 to 10 in C++? I have this but its not working.

`vector<int>test(10);
    test={ 1, 10 };`

Comment: Surely, you know about for loops, no?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`std::iota()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota):

```
std::vector<int> v(10);
std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 1);
```

Answer (score 6):

Another using `generate`:

```
vector<int>test(10);
int x = 0;
std::generate(test.begin(), test.end(), [&]{ return x++; });
```

Answer (score 3):

Many options. For example,

```
vector<int> test{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
```

or

```
std::vector<int> test;
test.reserve(10); // prevent some reallocations
for (int i = 1; i < 11; ++i)
  test.push_back(i);
```

or

```
std::vector<int> test(10);
std::iota(test.begin(), test.end(), 1);
```

Comment: `iota` feels incomplete with out a `iota_iterator`. I don't want to have to initialize something just to have it overwritten immediately. Maybe an `uninitialized_inserter` would help.

Comment: @KerrekSB I agree. I don't really use it it real code.

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<int> vInts;
for (int i=1;i<=10;++i){
    vInts.push_back(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use standard algorithm `std::iota` declared in header `<numeric>` For example

```
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

//...

std::vector<int> v( 10 );
std::iota( v.begin(), v.end(), 1 );
```